# Trying to apply inline-block to span

Tags: css

`inline-block` is not working for me here below.. no problem with `block`

```
<div class="delegacion" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/HomeAndConstructionBusiness">
  <h2>Delegación Madrid</h2>
  <span itemprop="streeAddress" class="new-line">Calle Guetaria 110</span>
  <span itemprop="postalCode">28041</span>
  <span itemprop="addressLocality" class="new-line">Madrid</span>
  <span itemprop="telephone" class="telephone new-line">
      <a href="tel:+683457946">683 457 946</a>
  </span>
```

CSS:

```
  span.new-line {
    display: inline-block;
  }
```

Comment: What is it that you are trying to do? if you have no problem with using `block` then just use `block`

Comment: What about <lu> <li> ?

Comment: Which browser are you viewing that stuff on? [Certain browsers](http://caniuse.com/inline-block) don't support inline-block.

Comment: @giorgian FF20 -------

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would generally use `inline-block` when you want an element to behave like an `inline` element but be able to respect properties such as height, width, top & bottom padding and margins.

Since you aren't setting any of those, you won't see a difference between `inline` and `inline-block`

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to have the `.new-line` items each be on their own line, then you have to use `block` instead of `inline-block`.

See jsFiddle  here: http://jsfiddle.net/25VQa/

The short answer is that you need to use block.